# Is room android library faster than the old way of accesing sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I was wondering if I should update my android app to use room, or keep using android.database.sqlite since as far as I know ORM are slower on speed in the case of entity framework in .Net but don't know if is the same case with this room ORM for mobile.

For opinions thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's more or less the same. Room "is" still sqlite, it is only on steroids to make developers life much easier using features to write better and cleaner code.

Comment: Thanks DM I thought since it was ORM operations would be slow like inserts and updates but it seems not

Comment: I would not bother with that too much. It depends how your structure is designed. Also, now we have better phones with bigger rams and cpu power. For insert and updates it is also important how many primary keys you have. But just for info. I was working on big projects and inserting 200k objects took me less than 200ms.